# Role of like in copular/linking verbs

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, linking-verbs, subject-complement

I'm struggling to make some distinctions regarding copular, or linking, verbs.

> 1. She sounds like a lawyer.
> 2. She has become like her mother.
> 3. She looks like a princess.

#1: Is "sounds" an intransitive verb with "like a lawyer" modifying "sounds"? Or is "sounds like" a copular verb phrase with "a lawyer" as a predicative nominal?

#2: Similar questions: is "become like" a copular verb? Is it just "Become"? Prepositional phrases cannot be subjective complements, right? So what is "like" in this context?

#3: Same questions as #2.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: ***sounds, become*** and ***looks*** are all copular verbs, ***adverbially*** modified by ***like** [something or other]*. Compare those adverbial usages with straightforward adjectives: *She sounds **upset**, She has become **wealthy**, She looks **happy***.

Comment: This could be a full answer. @FumbleFingers

Comment: But don't copular verbs require a complement? If "like a lawyer" and rest are adverbials, wouldn't that make them optional?

Comment: @Educator22 Why do you think adverbial complements are optional?

Comment: @FumbleFingers might be better for you to make your comments into answers, comments can be removed and you have a ton of high quality comments that should be answers :(

Comment: @DialFrost: I can't answer the *actual* point OP is querying here - as phrased in the comment *If "like a lawyer" and rest are adverbials, wouldn't that make them optional?* Perhaps you should take the OP to task for asking the real question in a comment! :)

Comment: OK, you're right, adverbial complements are not optional, my mistake. But I've typically understood adverbial complements as identifying location or time, like "The meeting is in five minutes," or "The book is on the shelf," and that these complements are distinct from adjectival/nominal complements, which determine the subject. "Like a lawyer" seems like a nominal complement, but you're saying it's adverbial, determining the subject?

Comment: @Educator22 There's only one copula: the verb "be". Other verbs like "seem", "prove", "feel" and a few others take PCs (predicative complements). In your example "The meeting is in five minutes", "in five minutes" is not adverbial, but a preposition phrase functioning as a complement.